# Alternate background color of form checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a simple form and want to alternate the background color of each option like you can for tables using CSS `tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}`

For the form I tried using ids that linked to CSS with different background colors:

```
function options(){
        var i =0;
        var name;
        $(xmlDoc).children().children().each(function(){
            name = $(this).children().first().text();
            if(i % 2 == 0){
                $('form').append(" <input type='checkbox' id=odd'" + "value=" + name + ">"+ name + "<br>");
            }
            else{
                $('form').append(" <input type='checkbox' id='even'" + "value=" + name + ">"+ name + "<br>");
            }
            i++;
        });
    }
```

but have found that you can only change the background color by indicating it in the form. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: If you could setup a `jsfiddle` it would make it easier to resolve

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the color of the form you have to call it from the form

`<form style="background-color: #E0FFFF"></form>`

and can't do anything for specific inputs.
To combat this I have found that you have to turn the entire thing into a list and then can use

`li:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2;}`

inside your CSS. The HTML looks like this:

`<ul style='list-style-type: none;><li><input type='checkbox' id='name' value='name'>name<br></li></ul>`

the styling of the ul is to get rid of bullet points.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
input[type="checkbox"]:nth-of-type(2n-1) {
background-color: #222222;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:nth-of-type(2n) {
background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```